# RSpec testing Time objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have failing specs relating to time.

I understand that times are calculated as seconds from epoch, but I would like this spec to pass if the object representations are close enough.

For example:

```
expect( @model.end_date ).to eq end_date

expected: Wed, 08 Feb 2017 20:13:30 UTC +00:00
     got: Wed, 08 Feb 2017 20:13:30 UTC +00:00
```

Does anyone have any advice on testing time so that a slight offset won't fail the test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use RSpec's built-in [`be_within` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher), which can be also be used for floating point numbers and other data types prone to slight discrepancies:

```
expect(@model.end_date).to be_within(1.second).of(end_date)
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you!

Comment: Also, note that if you had to compare strings instead of numeric reperesentations of dates, you could use a regex matcher.

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave the `eq` method but freeze the time of the spec with Timecop - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/liangzan-timecop/Timecop.freeze. Using `be_within` doesn't guarantee that the spec will pass.

Comment: Always fun to look back on these issues and realize how I've been solving the same problems for years lol. Time freezing and Timecop is a good solution I've come across in the last 4 years. I'd warn that if your software has features relating to time ranges (i.e. start, end), then it can introduce other problematics for tests. (e.g. Scheduling, Caching, etc).